# receiving radio box value in php

Tags: php, radio-button

I have 2 following radio boxes in a form,

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" class="radio" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no" class="radio" /> No
```

1. How can i recieve the value of the radio button once the form is posted (in PHP)
2. Once it is posted on the same page, how can I *remember* the selected radio button and keep that checked?
   Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1) The value of the radio button is saved in `$_POST` *only if* any of the choices was selected.

```
if (isset($_POST['radio']))   // if ANY of the options was checked
  echo $_POST['radio'];    // echo the choice
else
  echo "nothing was selected.";
```

---

2) Just check for the value and add `checked='checked'` if it matches.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" class="radio" <?php if (isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == 'yes'): ?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?> /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no"  class="radio" <?php if (isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] ==  'no'): ?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?> /> No
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" class="radio" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no" class="radio" /> No

 u get radio value using $_POST['radio'];
```

simple bro,

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" <?php if($_POST['radio']=="yes") echo "checked";?> value="yes" class="radio" /> Yes
```

u have to identify radio box by value man

Answer (score 2):

> How can i recieve the value of the radio button once the form is posted (in PHP)

```
$_POST['radio']
```

> Once it is posted on the same page, how can I remember the selected radio button and keep that checked?

Add a `checked` attribute `if` the value is equal to `$_POST['radio']`.

Answer (score 2):

1)  u will receive only  that radio box value  via **POST** which is *checked*

```
    $radio_value=$_POST['radio'];
```

2)

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" class="radio" 
   <?php echo ($radio_value == 'yes') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no" class="radio" 
   <?php echo ($radio_value == 'no') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/> No
```

Comment: there should be errors/mistake on your code. Please correct me :)

Comment: @alumi would you please like to mention the error/mistake/typo, and of course go ahead to fix it :)

Comment: <?php echo ($radio_value == 'yes') ?> - you closed the PHP tag, and then you use the PHP Short IF statement?

Comment: @alumi thanks for pointing. I corrected it and btw its a ternary operator.