# Insert data from HTML field and bootstrap popup window

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html form with one text field and one bootstrap module popup and two types of submit.

I'am able to collect the value from the html field using `$_POST` but I'am not getting the value from the popup window.

HTML :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <form id="contactform" method="post" action="http://****/post.php">
  <tr>
   <td>
     <label for="name">Name :</label>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="text" name="name">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      &nbsp;
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Update</button>
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="plan">Plan :</label>
                       <input type="radio" name="plan" value="Yes" > Yes</input>
                       <input type="radio" name="plan" value="No"> No</input>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" formaction="update.php" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
         </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here for two submits am using two php files: `post.php` and `update.php`
Where one submit is outside (post.php) the popup and other inside (update.php) the popup.
In `post.php` I am only collecting text field using

```
$name =  $_POST['name'];
```

Which is working, but not in `update.php` code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
if($conn === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
}
 $name =  $_POST['name'];
 $plan =  $_POST['plan'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, plan) VALUES ('$name', '$plan')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
   echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
 ?>
```

Here in db I'am only able to collect name.

Please help to collect the values form both html field (name) and popup window field (plan).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167596/receiving-radio-box-value-in-php

Comment: Its for the radio buttons, am facing difficulty in collecting the value from popup window and the html field outside popup window together.Can you please let me know how to collect value from both together.

Comment: Ok, but you have `formaction="update.php"` on button in popup. So it doesn't go together. Should it go in same row in database or?

Comment: db has three columns id,name,plan....yes they have to go into the same row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your button in popup remove `data-dismiss` like this:

`<button type="submit" formaction="update.php" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>`

Then in your `post.php` process just `$name` and in `update.php` `$plan` and `$post`.

Comment: Den how will the update.php will get fired..?
In post.php am only inserting name that too in different table,but in the popup when submitted i want to fire update.php,where it collects both name and plan and insert in db ...

Comment: Thats what I asked you in comments. If you just insert it then check if it is set and insert. But if you need update then leave `formaction`. Nothing else.

Comment: post.php for name
update.php for both name and plan

if update was to collect only plan i was able to collect,but here i want both name and plan

Comment: same thing.. it will pass both in `update.php` and in `post.php` you just insert name.

Comment: ok..Thank you used the formation but removed data-dismiss as suggested, It worked..thank you....